# SVG with image tag inside is not displaying for android and iphone

Tags: iphone, image, mobile, svg, android-browser

I have severals svg in a hybrid app, and some of them contain an image tag (for shadows)

sample:

```
<svg version="1.1"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
x="0px" y="0px" width="155px" height="55.4px" viewBox="0 0 155 55.4" enable-background="new 0 0 155 55.4" xml:space="preserve">

<g>
<image overflow="visible" opacity="0.75" width="646" height="231" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw.... ....></image>
</g>
<g><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M47,6.3h14v0.1l-6.6,4.1H47...8,6.3,47,6.3z"/></g>
</svg>
```

the shadows (which are in the image tag) are visible in all desktop browser, and chrome on android.
but not in iphone or native android browser.

do I have to delete the shadow for mobile or is there a way to display them for mobile too ?

Comment: What versions of iOS and android? How are you using the svg? Referenced from some <img> tags?

Comment: I used my the svg as a background-image in css. I have the problem on android 4.2 and ios latest version